# changing opacity based on different column using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, opacity

I would like to change the opacity of the bar based on a value in a different column. here is a simple example. if the  gdpPercap <20000 I want to change the opacity to 0.5 for instance. I also have a discrete color map that assigns colors based on the decade, for instance 1980-1990 is green , 1990-2000 is red. Within this color map I am looking to change the opacity of the bars.

```
import plotly.express as px
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a column with the newly standardized Gross Domestic Product values. (from 0 to 1) Specify a continuous colormap with that column as the color target. Specify the transparency of that color specification in RGBA. The threshold value of 0.4 is set appropriately, so change it to your threshold value.

```
import plotly.express as px

data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")

data_canada_ = data_canada.copy()
s = data_canada_['gdpPercap']
data_canada_['gdpPercap_min_max'] = (s - s.min()) / (s.max() - s.min())

fig = px.bar(data_canada_,
             x='year', y='pop',
             color='gdpPercap_min_max',
             color_continuous_scale=[(0, "rgba(65,105,225,1.0)"), (0.4, "rgba(65,105,225,0.5)"), (1.0, "rgba(65,105,225,0.5)")])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks this is useful but i am not sure if this answers my question

Comment: How is it that you do not know if my answer is the answer?

Comment: @r-beginners i just came across a very similar use case. i think part of what `qfd` was asking is how we can change the opacity but keep the distinct color of the each bars distinct. in my case, i have a grouped bar chart with multiple values for each of the different categories, and I want the different bar groups to have a different color, and the opacity of all of the bars depend on a different column

Comment: I read the question again and your point is correct. I may need to loop through the graph object, specifying color and transparency for each category. upvote thanks!